# Not properly functioning virtual 7.1

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, bsod, headset

I recently bought a F.R.E.Q. 7 headset by Mad Catz, and I have quite a problem with its virtual 7.1.

I found out about it after I installed the drivers and tried to use the 7.1.
It worked, however it seemed that all the sound (Anything, whether that's games, music or video) was being combined and came from only one virtual speaker of all 8 that should be working. I tried reinstalling the software pack through the control panel menu, however that did not help.

I decided to see whether there were any incompatibilities between the software and my rig. I wiped one of my drives (a 128 GB SSD, which I use for the OS, drivers and other performance and system important things), and reinstalled the OS. I than installed only the following: the Gigabyte motherboard driver pack and the Nvidia one, which were required to maintain the system afloat.
My motherboard comes with an integrated Creative Sound Blaster Recon3Di, but I uninstalled all the drivers and software assosciated with it and nothing changed with the headset's 7.1.

I also tried the headset on a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga laptop, where with drivers installed the 7.1 worked perfectly, and my work Lenovo Ideacentre A730 PC where with the drivers installed the headset did not work like on the home one (I built my PC myself, and so there is no full driver packages or anything from the manufacturer).

The supplier of the drivers is Conexant, who has a folder in the program files. There were two folders inside - inside one named CNXT_AUDIO_USB_DH there were a couple of install exes (Named ISUIU and UIU64), with GUI's back from the 90's, and these as well the whole contents of the folder were related to the F.R.E.Q. 7, since there were files with appropriate file names. I tried activating those, the installers completed the installation, and as a result my computer BSOD'ed with the classic error "boot drive loading failed".

There was also a separate Dolby folder in the conexant one, which was again dedicated to the F.R.E.Q. 7. The contents include DolbyHID.exe, DolbyHID config file, and setup 64. Those were also activated and supposedly were a cause for my bluescreen adventures asd well.

I got over my SSD failure and somewhat little losses that came with it (I store all the documents on the HDD), and tried to look up a different version of the conexant drivers on the internet, however those were from lenovo/dell and refused to work due to my rig being custom not coming from either of those manufacturers.

Is there anything I can do to get the headset's 7.1 working or am I left with stereo forever (which is sad, since the virtual 7.1 is indeed great)?